# What's the most effective way to learn and revise foreign language vocabulary?

Tags: memory, language

Google searches have suggested to me that some sort of spaced repetition should work best, keeping in mind [Ebbinghaus's "Forgetting Curve"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetting_curve). However, it is not clear to me exactly when I should schedule my learning/revision sessions, or the format the learning/revision sessions should take.

There are programs such as [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) and [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com/) that purport to present revision material at an appropriate spacing, but I don't know how I can assess whether the spacing those programs suggest is truly appropriate.

Comment: the whole point of anki is that when used appropriately, the spacing schedule will be calibrated specifically to that item.